# Entity Framework - Use 2 DBContext for the same Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a solution where I want to add another project with it's own DBcontext, using its own tables, in the same database as the rest of the solution (the 2 DBcontexts are not sharing any tables). 
But when running the project I am getting the error below:

> Additional information: The default DbConfiguration instance was used
>   by the Entity Framework before the 'Configuration' type was
>   discovered. An instance of 'Configuration' must be set at application
>   start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered
>   in the application's config file.

I already have a big database built in the existing solution, so I don't want to change anything there, if I can avoid that. I have tried to change the `ContextKey` in the configuration and also tried to use another DB schema for the new project, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699#Moving

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the codeConfigurationType in web.config and that solved my problem :-)

Comment: @SteveGreene, that should be posted as an answer. ;)

Comment: @RamiA. - I disagree - the problem described by the OP is indicating the instance of 'Configuration' must be set before using EF.  The article in the link by Steve Green does not describe how to set the instance.

Comment: @barrypicker, I've isolated the solution in the answer I just posted. Hope that helps you!

Comment: @RamiA. - Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The link provided in the first comment to the question by [steve-green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1549450/steve-greene) solves the issue.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699#Moving:

> ... use the config file to specify the `DbConfiguration` instance to use. To do this, set the `codeConfigurationType` attribute of the `entityFramework` section. For example:
>   
>   `<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyNamespace.MyDbConfiguration, MyAssembly"> 
>       ...Your EF config... 
>   </entityFramework>`

Answer (score 0):

So first of all can we conclude that only one Dbconfiguration can be used.

The attribute option `"[DbConfigurationType(typeof(myDbCOnfig))]"` only helps the `dbContext` to use the `DbConfiguration` from another assembly.

If you have multi assemblies with their own dbContext, you can set `"entityFramework codeConfigurationType="[YourDbConfig]""` in your `web.config` file once and not set `DbConfigurationType` attribute for every individual `dbcontext`